# Autocorrelation of a random process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, correlation

Let X be a random process. X(t) = A*Cos(wt+θ) ; where A and w are constants. The only random thing is θ. Lets say θ has a probability density function,

f(θ)= 1/2pi for 0<θ<2pi and zero elsewhere.

My confusion starts here.

Auto correlation function R(t) is defined as E[X(t) * X(t + τ)]. fine! Afterall closer the values X(t) and X(t+τ) are, higher will the "correlation" value. It makes sense till now.

Then, the text says that

**R(t)** = ∫X(t)*X(t+τ)*f(θ)dθ **[integration limits from 0 to 2pi]**. I dont understand why we have f(θ) here. θ was present within X(t) i.e inside Cos term, I dont see why its effect is in multplication like this.

Ofcourse since f(θ) is 1/2pi, its like finding the mean of ∫X(t)*X(t+τ)dθ afterall that is what expectancy is.

But still I feel hole.What if pdf of θ was piece wise continuous like

f(θ) = 1/2pi ; 0<θ<pi
= 1/6pi ; pi<θ<4pi
= 0     ; elsewhere

Kindly help me understand why we have f(θ) term multiplied there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's change the notation a little bit. Let $g(t,\theta) = A\cos(\omega t + \theta) = X(t)$. My guess is that the text was supposed to be,

$$R(t) = E[X(t)X(t+\tau)] = E[g(t,\theta)g(t+\tau,\theta)] = \int g(t,\theta)g(t+\tau,\theta)f(\theta)\,d\theta.$$

I think they simply substituted $X(t)$ for $g(t,\theta)$ and $X(t+\tau)$ for $g(t+\tau,\theta)$ in the expression above, hiding the dependence of $X(t)$ and $X(t+\tau)$ on $\theta$.

Comment: I dont understand why we have f(theta) here

Comment: Oh, that's just by definition of the expectation and probability distribution function. Think of $\theta$ as a random variable with pdf $f$. Then for any function $h$, $E[h(\theta)] = \int h(\theta)f(\theta)\,d\theta$. In this case, we let $h(\theta) = g(t,\theta)g(t+\tau,\theta)$.